# How to add button to UITableViewController in static cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController`,and have set its content to `Static Cells`,style to `grouped`.
My question is how to add the red button to the tableview appropriately,Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the footer of the table. Apparently it is not part of any cell.

Comment: Maybe tonight, when I have access to my iOS projects. I cannot promise though. 
However, it is not that difficult. You just create a plain view with a button, set the delegate to your view controller and assign this as the footer view ot the tableview object.